# Pandas: Find date of last edit for each element in Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Hope to express myself correctly in the following as it seems to be a complicated one.

My department is regularly creating daily snapshots at random times for our current project portfolio website. Below, I have filtered the entire table for all snapshot with project_id = 1. Filtering here to make it more understandable as there are many projects. Moreover, I have reduced the number of columns for this example.

df_table

```
project_id  project_name  region  style   effect   representative lazy  timestamp
1           PullPressure  EU      A-B-C   Pull     Martin         DCA   10/01/20
1           PullPressure  EU      A-B-C   Pull     Martin         DCA   09/05/20
1           PushPressure  EU      A-B-C   Push     Martin               08/20/20
1           PressurePush  EU      A-B-C   Push     Martin               04/06/20
1           PressurePush  US      A-B-C   Push     Johnsson             12/31/19
1           PressurePush  US      A-B-C   Push     Johnsson             10/15/19
```

My goal is to find out when the last change for any columns of project_id (or in general any key_column) has occurred, i.e. when was each cell for a given id last edited?

My goal is to achieve something like this:

df_table_new:

```
project_id  project_name region       style        effect       representative  lazy        timestamp
1           08/20/20     04/06/20     10/15/19     09/05/20     04/06/20        09/05/20    10/01/20
1           08/20/20     04/06/20     10/15/19     09/05/20     04/06/20        09/05/20    09/05/20
1           08/20/20     04/06/20     10/15/19     10/15/19     04/06/20        10/15/19    08/20/20
1           10/15/19     04/06/20     10/15/19     10/15/19     04/06/20        10/15/19    04/06/20
1           10/15/19     10/15/19     10/15/19     10/15/19     10/15/19        10/15/19    12/31/19
1           10/15/19     10/15/19     10/15/19     10/15/19     10/15/19        10/15/19    10/15/19
```

Please let me know in case anything is unclear!

edit: having null values inside the column, results in an NaT error as such:

```
lazy
09/05/20
09/05/20
NaT
NaT
NaT
NaT
```

Whereas, instead of NaT the values the fields should refer to the oldest available timestamp in timestamp column, which is 10/15/19.

edit2: Solved with the solution of @jezrael by adding the respective elements to the function. Well appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) for each column generated by [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%m/%d/%y')

for c in df.columns.difference(['project_id','timestamp']):
    df[c] = df.groupby(['project_id',c], sort=False)['timestamp'].transform('last')
print (df)

   project_id project_name     region      style     effect representative  \
0           1   2020-09-05 2020-04-06 2019-10-15 2020-09-05     2020-04-06   
1           1   2020-09-05 2020-04-06 2019-10-15 2020-09-05     2020-04-06   
2           1   2020-08-20 2020-04-06 2019-10-15 2019-10-15     2020-04-06   
3           1   2019-10-15 2020-04-06 2019-10-15 2019-10-15     2020-04-06   
4           1   2019-10-15 2019-10-15 2019-10-15 2019-10-15     2019-10-15   
5           1   2019-10-15 2019-10-15 2019-10-15 2019-10-15     2019-10-15   

   timestamp  
0 2020-10-01  
1 2020-09-05  
2 2020-08-20  
3 2020-04-06  
4 2019-12-31
```

If need original format add [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%m/%d/%y')

for c in df.columns.difference(['project_id','timestamp']):
    df[c] = (df.groupby(['project_id',c], sort=False)['timestamp'].transform('last')
               .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y'))
print (df)

   project_id project_name    region     style    effect representative  \
0           1     09/05/20  04/06/20  10/15/19  09/05/20       04/06/20   
1           1     09/05/20  04/06/20  10/15/19  09/05/20       04/06/20   
2           1     08/20/20  04/06/20  10/15/19  10/15/19       04/06/20   
3           1     10/15/19  04/06/20  10/15/19  10/15/19       04/06/20   
4           1     10/15/19  10/15/19  10/15/19  10/15/19       10/15/19   
5           1     10/15/19  10/15/19  10/15/19  10/15/19       10/15/19   

   timestamp  
0 2020-10-01  
1 2020-09-05  
2 2020-08-20  
3 2020-04-06  
4 2019-12-31  
5 2019-10-15
```

EDIT: Add `fillna` by minimal timestamp:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%m/%d/%y')
min1 = df['timestamp'].min()

for c in df.columns.difference(['project_id','timestamp']):
    df[c] = df.groupby(['project_id',c], sort=False)['timestamp'].transform('last').fillna(min1)
print (df)
   project_id project_name     region      style     effect representative  \
0           1   2020-09-05 2020-04-06 2019-10-15 2020-09-05     2020-04-06   
1           1   2020-09-05 2020-04-06 2019-10-15 2020-09-05     2020-04-06   
2           1   2020-08-20 2020-04-06 2019-10-15 2019-10-15     2020-04-06   
3           1   2019-10-15 2020-04-06 2019-10-15 2019-10-15     2020-04-06   
4           1   2019-10-15 2019-10-15 2019-10-15 2019-10-15     2019-10-15   
5           1   2019-10-15 2019-10-15 2019-10-15 2019-10-15     2019-10-15   

        lazy  timestamp  
0 2020-09-05 2020-10-01  
1 2020-09-05 2020-09-05  
2 2019-10-15 2020-08-20  
3 2019-10-15 2020-04-06  
4 2019-10-15 2019-12-31  
5 2019-10-15 2019-10-15
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this! I may ask, is there a way to include a second keycolumn to look for, e.g. project_id1 and project_id2?

Comment: @Botan - then change `.groupby(['project_id',c]` to `.groupby(['project_id1','project_id2', c]`

Comment: .@jezrael would there be a way to replace NaT values with the oldest date in the timestamp? in some instances, there are null values whch should be replaced with the oldest value of the timestamp as there has never been a change to the element in the table

Comment: @Botan - Is possible be more specific? Is possible change data for one column for see this replacement?

Comment: .@jezrael - yes I have added a new column "lazy" which consists of null values. Hope the explanation in the edit gives good insights into the issue.